# Javascript Reducing the Array to Desired Format

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reduce

I am trying to reduce the array as efficiently as possible. My current array looks like this:

```
myArr = [
    {cat: "Wires", subCat: "Wires & Connection", description: "Demo Description for Green Wire", id: 4049, name: "green_wire"},
    {cat: "Wires", subCat: "Wires & Connection", description: "Demo Description for Red Wire", id: 1224, name: "red_wire"},
    {cat: "Fixtures", subCat: "Lights", description: "The Bullet FL2832B uplight casts a broad, flatteri…s include an included heavy-duty composite stake.", id: 1360, name: "bullet_lights"},
    {cat: "Fixtures", subCat: "Spot Lights", description: "Demo Description for Walkway Lights", id: 8602, name: "walkway_lights"},
    {cat: "Controls", subCat: "Power Sources", description: "Description for 600w SS Transformer", id: 7738, name: "600w_ss_transformer"},
    {cat: "", subCat: "", description: "Project Background Image", id: 8029, name: "bgImg"}
];
```

And I want to reduce this array to this format by sorting children based on "cat" first and then inside "cat", I want to sort the children based on "subCat". Something like this:

```
final = [
    {
        cat: "Wires",
        children : [
            {
                subCat: "Wires & Connection",
                children: [
                    {cat: "Wires", subCat: "Wires & Connection", description: "Demo Description for Green Wire", id: 4049, name: "green_wire"},
                    {cat: "Wires", subCat: "Wires & Connection", description: "Demo Description for Red Wire", id: 1224, name: "red_wire"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        cat: "Fixtures",
        children : [
            {
                subCat: "Lights",
                children : [
                    {cat: "Fixtures", subCat: "Lights", description: "The Bullet FL2832B uplight casts a broad, flatteri…s include an included heavy-duty composite stake.", id: 1360, name: "bullet_lights"}
                ]
            },
            {
                subCat: "Spot Lights",
                children : [
                    {cat: "Fixtures", subCat: "Spot Lights", description: "Demo Description for Walkway Lights", id: 8602, name: "walkway_lights"}  
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        cat: "Controls",
        children : [
            {
                subCat: "Power Sources",
                children: [
                    {cat: "Controls", subCat: "Power Sources", description: "Description for 600w SS Transformer", id: 7738, name: "600w_ss_transformer"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        cat: "",
        children : [
            {
                subCat: "",
                children: [
                    {cat: "", subCat: "", description: "Project Background Image", id: 8029, name: "bgImg"}  
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So far, I have tried this but this organize the array only by "subCat". I want to nest it further down to "cat":

```
    const formatedObjects = objects.reduce((acc, d) => {
      const found = acc.find(a => a.subCat === d.subCat);
      const value = { 
        id: d.id,
        name: d.name,
        subCat: d.subCat,
        cat: d.cat,
        description: d.description
        }; // the element in data property
      if (!found) {
        acc.push({subCat:d.subCat, children: [value]}) // not found, so need to add data property
      }
      else {
        found.data.push(value) // if found, that means data property exists, so just push new element to found.data.
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
```

Any idea how can i do this efficiently?

Comment: Please share your attempts. We will try to optimize/improve it if needed.

Comment: Updated the question with what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If optional chaining is available could do something like:

```js
const array = [{
    cat: "Wires",
    subCat: "Wires & Connection",
    description: "Demo Description for Green Wire",
    id: 4049,
    name: "green_wire",
  },
  {
    cat: "Wires",
    subCat: "Wires & Connection",
    description: "Demo Description for Red Wire",
    id: 1224,
    name: "red_wire",
  },
  {
    cat: "Fixtures",
    subCat: "Lights",
    description: "The Bullet FL2832B uplight casts a broad, flatteri…s include an included heavy-duty composite stake.",
    id: 1360,
    name: "bullet_lights",
  },
  {
    cat: "Fixtures",
    subCat: "Spot Lights",
    description: "Demo Description for Walkway Lights",
    id: 8602,
    name: "walkway_lights",
  },
  {
    cat: "Controls",
    subCat: "Power Sources",
    description: "Description for 600w SS Transformer",
    id: 7738,
    name: "600w_ss_transformer",
  },
  {
    cat: "",
    subCat: "",
    description: "Project Background Image",
    id: 8029,
    name: "bgImg",
  },
];

const final = array.reduce((list, item) => {
  const {
    cat,
    subCat
  } = item;
  const hasList = !!list ? .[cat];
  const subList = list ? .[cat] ? .children.find(
    (child) => child.subCat === subCat
  );

  if (!hasList) {
    list[cat] = {
      cat,
      children: [{
        subCat,
        children: [item],
        count: 1,
      }, ],
    };
  } else if (!subList) {
    list[cat].children.push({
      subCat,
      children: [item],
      count: 1,
    });
  } else {
    subList.count += 1;
    subList.children.push(item);
  }

  return list;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(final));
```

Comment: This return a final object. Anyway i can get it as array ?

Comment: I believe Object.values but will need to verify!

Comment: Updated the code sample. I believe it should now match the desired output. When it comes to efficiency, it is difficult to determine without more details because it depends on what benchmarks one is optimizing for and the environment where the code will be run.

Comment: Any way I can include the "count" key in the output using the above reducer if the two items inside subchildren has same name?

Comment: @KartikSolanki Yes, since we are mutating and not affecting anything in an outside scope, we can add the count field to the children and iterate it when a new child comes in for the subCategory.